# Advanced Effects in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've been trying to recreate [this GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJtT5.png) purely in WPF, and I'm having problems:

[image]

- The shadow. The shadow on the main element doesn't show inside the fill - when using DropShadowEffect in WPF, it does. As of yet I've found no solution to this.
- Background images - the main element has a slight pattern in it, a diagonal one. But in WPF, I can't use background images like this. Chances are I'm just missing something.
- The slight inset, in the main element (at the top) - not easily replicated.

So anyway, I guess my question is, how can I accomplish these kinds of effects in WPF?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying about the shadow, but If you do not define a background for the shadowed element, its children will show the shadow too... so just define a background to the element where you applied the effect and it shall be visible only on the outside.

The diagonal pattern do not have to be an image - look here http://blog.pixelingene.com/2008/09/quick-tip-to-get-a-striped-background/

The inset can be simulated by just drawing a line... zoom in on that image and you will see that is just a darker line that give this effect.

Comment: I remember you were trying to hide the shadow inside translucent rectangle. Now, you want to show the shadow? Not clear... please post code and more details (comments).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully this snippet will point you in the right direction:

```
<Grid>
    <Border x:Name="Blur"
            BorderThickness="5"
            CornerRadius="5"
            BorderBrush="#7F000000">
        <Border.Effect>
            <BlurEffect Radius="8" />
        </Border.Effect>
    </Border>
    <Border x:Name="Outter"
            BorderBrush="#CCD3D3D3"
            BorderThickness="1"
            CornerRadius="5"
            Margin="2">
        <Border.Background>
            <ImageBrush Viewbox="0,0,45,38"
                        ViewboxUnits="Absolute"
                        Viewport="0,0,45,38"
                        ViewportUnits="Absolute"
                        TileMode="Tile"
                        ImageSource="<SomeImageThatIsATileOfThePattern>"
                        Opacity="0.3"
                        Stretch="Fill" />
        </Border.Background>
    </Border>
    <Border x:Name="Inner"
            BorderThickness="0,1,0,0"
            CornerRadius="5"
            Margin="2,4,2,2"
            BorderBrush="#7FD3D3D3" />
    <ItemsControl Background="HotPink"
                  Margin="11"
                  Height="21" />
</Grid>
```

The result is:

[image: The result]

[I used a generic image, just to show the repetition. The original image is W50xH38 in size - hope the repetition is noticeable]

Play with the values for Viewbox and Viewport to adjust to your image.

Of course, the `ItemsControl` should not have the pink background and its height should not be a constant, it was done for demo purposes.

Comment: Wow, this is excellent! It's worked perfectly so far. :D One question: how do I prevent the blurred border from bleeding inside Outer?

Comment: Also, I'm having a very hard time getting the shadow too look very realistic.